# memorizing values in variables VS using functions/methods that return values

Tags: c#, java, c++, function, memory

I have been wandering about this for some time now. I'm still a beginner, so my programs are simple and require almost no resources. I'm familiar with C++, Java and C#. But in the future things will get more complicated, with more variables and objects and more functions/methods.

In order to change the value of a variable, I can call a function/method, that changes the value, once. After that when I need the variable, I have to simply call it. It takes less time to get the value. If the function does a lot of work, the time that it has consumed will be experienced only once. But the variables require space in the memory and when their quantity gets quite big, this can become a problem.

But I can call a function/method that returns the value I need. I will only need to use variables where necessary, which means- less variables. It's not a problem if the function/method is short. But some functions/methods must do quite a lot of work before they return the value. This way the program will seem slower for the user.

My question is: memorizing values in variables VS using functions/methods that return the value: which is better, when and why?

This question sounds like: high speed and more consumed memory VS less consumed memory and low speed...

Comment: If your question is not language-specific, don't just spam it with every language tag you can think of; that's not constructive.

Comment: In my case, these are the languages I'm familiar with. I can add a tag for "not language-specific" (I don't remember the name of that tag), but less people will see it...

Comment: Less people may see it, but at least your question won't be disingenuous and show up for people who really only want to answer language-specific questions (such as myself :-P).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually wise to avoid caching values which can be computed, since then you can avoid having to maintain state in separate places (and breaking consistency if you eventually forget).

It is a good idea to abstract away on the calculation of some value (like hiding it behind a function). Later once your code works and you feel it slow, then use profiling to determine the hotspots. If such a function turns out to be a hotspot, you can introduce caching / memoizing underneath, and the abstraction (in an ideal world) will cover the nasty details from the client (of the function).

**Memoization**

Memoizing a function usually involves a lookup table (based on array, associative array, etc.) with a key type being the aggregate of the arguments of the memoized function, and the stored value being the return value of the function.

Then, the function would first check if the result is already available in the lookup table and return it, or else compute the result and store it before returning.

In fact, such memoization could be disjoined from the memoized function, and implemented as a separate layer (wrapping the function) if the programming language supports such abstraction. In languages without first-class functions, this can usually be achieved using interfaces and single-method classes.

Comment: Sidenote: In C++, a const member function performing some slow calculation can cache the result in a mutable member. However this is pretty messy already (well, C++).

Answer (score 7):

You are pointing out that **you can sometimes trade worse space efficiency for better time efficiency**, or, of course, the opposite.

Which is better? Obviously it depends on the answer to the question: **Which do you have less of available, space or time?**

Bing needs to do a search of the entire internet in a fraction of a second; time is *extremely expensive* and space is *extremely cheap* for the Bing team, so they always choose to go for the solution that is time-efficient even if it means using extra space.

Some people work on problems where they can burn time, but they can't put more memory in the machine because the machine is, say, in orbit around Mars.  Those people tend to optimize for improved space efficiency over improved time efficiency.

You make the tradeoff that is appropriate given your actual situation. No one way is obviously better than another *until you consider the actual costs*.

Comment: I expected a such answer. But, thanks!

Comment: @Александър Александров Of course. It's **the** correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to keep in mind with doing Object Oriented Programming (as you have C#, Java and C++) as tags is that classes should have **tight cohesion** and **loose coupling**.

In your question you state...

> But some functions/methods must do quite a lot of work before they
>   return the value

A tightly cohesize class will strive to fulfill a single, focused purpose and the methods that are apart of that class will follow suit.

In terms of maintainability and overall good Object Oriented Programming, having large methods that do all sorts of computations to bring back a value instead of having tightly cohesive encapsulated classes is bad practice.

Maintaining a bunch of large, complicated methods that return a computed value instead of just having private variables that are used in well defined methods could be a developer's worst nightmare.